# What are some training types that strengthen getting up muscles?

Tags: workout, squats, calf, lower-body-strength, quads

While standing in a position like this

[image]

I want to be able to jump off the ground easily with one foot). Normal squats don't work well for this kind of a movement. Pistol squat is a better practice, but to do that you have to have a certain strength. Though, I can do it while holding the wall and that will be my choice if I don't find any better workouts. So what other types of workouts can I do to increase this strength?

Comment: Why do you think normal squats will not help you here? They would help strengthen the legs and prepare you for the pistols.

Comment: I think that way because I cant do 1 pistol without help while I can do 50 normal squats.. Btw in both squat and pistol the heel is on the ground, and in the move that I want to do the heel is off the ground, so I am not sure if that makes a difference..

Answer (score 4):

- Deeper, loaded squats, for instance, kettlebell goblet squats
- Assisted one-leg ("pistol") squats
- Loaded Turkish get-ups